# .NET JavaScript Unable To Retrieve Files

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

In my .NET Core 2 application I have a directory called "data" in the "wwwroot" section that has a few files. In JavaScript I am calling these files to load them into another JS function.

```
var filename = ["data/file1.kml", "data/file2.kml", "data/file3.kml"];
```

I thought that perhaps I needed to add a ~/ in front of the word data but that didn't seem to change anything. In the Chrome Console JavaScript is giving a 404 not found.

In a non .net site (php site) I could just provide the /data/filename.ext and could load the file in easily.

How can I retrieve files from a directory in .net?

**EDIT:**

So I added a .txt file to that dir and I can view it by going to

https://localhost:44300/data/info.txt

I should be able to go to the below to view one of the files

https://localhost:44300/data/file1.kml

*All files in the data directory are not part of the .net site. They are sitting in a folder on the server. I have them copied locally for debugging as well. The files in that folder will change all the time and the names will change as well. I already have something to get the contents of the directory when this happens I just can't load the .kml files but the .txt files will load.*

**EDIT:**

I made a copy of one of the files and replaced kml with xml for the extension and that does work.

https://localhost:44300/data/test.xml

Something to do with the .KML extension. I do have the MIME type added to the server (which didn't change anything), but this issue is also on localhost which I don't believe has MIME types you can edit. Is there something in the startup.cs file perhaps that needs to be added to support uncommon extension types?

**How would one go about adding support for a file extension type within a .NET application itself?**

I enabled directory listing and the .xml and .txt files display / load fine but the .kml and .gpx files show a 404.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will need to add more context to your question. All files in the wwwroot folder are available by default

Comment: Did you `app.UseStaticFiles()`?

Comment: Go to the file into VS, go to the properties of the file and check is "copy always/copy if never" (by default they are never copied); make sure this option is set correctly.

Comment: @TiGrex the only problem with that is that the files are on the server only and different files could be added anytime so I can't specify individual file properties locally. I just have a few test files locally for testing*.

Comment: @PieDev are they not working into localhost or the server?

Comment: @TiGreX I provided a more clear description in my question. I have the same set of files on my local system for testing.

Comment: @PieDev thats why Iam asking if is the server or your machine. normally the IIS don't return "weird" extensions. it is called MIME type filtering, have a quick look  if this can be the reason.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes I have had that in there

Comment: @TiGreX So the issue is on both the local dev machine and the server. If it worked locally but not on the server than it would make more sense but it does not even load the .kml extension locally. Is there a way to add support for file extension types within the .NET application itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS (generally) would not serve static files whose type it does not have in its mime map. And both `.kml` and `.gpx` are not in its mime map by default.

On IIS, you can add mime types by going to: IIS > Mime Types

In ASP.NET Core, you can do this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    // Add new mappings
    provider.Mappings[".kml"] = "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml";
    provider.Mappings[".gpx"] = "application/gpx+xml";

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = provider });
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x